# How to prevent Option+Command+Space from opening "Searching This Mac"?

Tags: macos, keyboard

The following keyboard shortcut will always bring up a window that says *Searching "This Mac"*:

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

I would like to use this shortcut for another purpose.  Is there any way to disable this shortcut?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. Go to **System Preferences** → **Spotlight** and uncheck the box for the **Spotlight window keyboard shortcut**. Alternatively, replace the shortcut with a different shortcut.

[image]

You can also enable/disable/modify the shortcut through **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Spotlight** → **Show Spotlight Window**:

[image]

Comment: That was it, thanks!  (I kept looking in the keyboard area of system preferences)

Comment: @KirkWoll It's *also* in the keyboard pane! :) (See edit)

Comment: you're right!  I think the main problem is I didn't realize that "Search My Mac" window had anything to do with "Spotlight". :)